# How to get elements in flexbox to span vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a layout with a mobile first approach with seven elements.

On larger screen I want to order them differently witch works fine.

But is it possible to span an item vertically in a row flexbox?

The element I want to span is element 6 witch will have a height that can vary much (i.e. I want to span element 6 over element 2 and 4).

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lellky/tvbrty83/

This is the container element

```
.product-description {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

And this is the code for one item:

```
.product-description .item-1 {
    order: 1;
    width: 67%;
    background-color: khaki;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you switch to flex-flow: col in the media query ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with flexbox. Only thing you could do is nest element 4 into element 2.

A workaround would be to use a negative margin on the box that you want to span:

```
.product-description .item-6 {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    margin-bottom: -160px;
}
```

You could do this with JS like this:

```
$('.item-6').css('margin-bottom', $('.item-4').outerHeight() * (-1));
```

see here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvbrty83/2/)

But remember that you have to do this on every window resize.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Seems to me then that there is no solution other than using position absolute or something.